# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value of string to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got issue with my SQL as below statement. After execute it, got error :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ONWARDS' to data
> type int.

```
SELECT description, moreThanDay, 
CONCAT(moreThanDay+1,' - ' , 
  IIF(LEAD(moreThanDay) OVER (ORDER BY moreThanDay) > 0, 
    LEAD(moreThanDay) OVER (ORDER BY moreThanDay),'ONWARDS')) AS rangeDay 
FROM EquipmentOwnerDetention WHERE equipmentOwnerCode=@equipmentOwnerCode
```

Is anyone know on how to cast so that the result will turn out as string ?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in IIF is int and 'ONWARDS' is string. IIF expects both to be of same data type. Try converting the first parameter to string and it may work.

Something like this

```
SELECT description, moreThanDay, 
CONCAT(moreThanDay+1,' - ' , 
  IIF(LEAD(moreThanDay) OVER (ORDER BY moreThanDay) > 0, 
    STR(LEAD(moreThanDay) OVER (ORDER BY moreThanDay), 10),'ONWARDS')) AS rangeDay 
FROM EquipmentOwnerDetention WHERE equipmentOwnerCode=@equipmentOwnerCode
```

Comment: Hi Shreyas, thanks for your help. It seems work. may i know what is the 10 indicate for ?

Comment: Thats for converting int to string, just gave 10 assuming the integer value is not more than 10 digits, you can change it as per your need

Comment: Ok got it, i did changed it too digit 2 instead, Thanks ya :)

Comment: This won't work because it is still concatenating a string with text.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because `moreThanDay` appears to be numeric, and you can't directly concatenate a numeric value to a string.  For brevity, I might include a CTE here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(moreThanDay) OVER (ORDER BY moreThanDay) moreThanDayLead
    FROM EquipmentOwnerDetention
    WHERE equipmentOwnerCode = @equipmentOwnerCode
)

SELECT description, moreThanDay,
       CONCAT(CAST(moreThanDay, VARCHAR(max)), ' - ',
              IIF(moreThanDayLead > 0, CAST(moreThanDayLead, VARCHAR(max)), 'ONWARDS')) AS rangeDay
FROM cte;
```

Comment: hi Tim, Thanks for your response too ya :) really appreciate it